# How can access preferences set in account-authenticator in Android

Tags: android-authenticator, authenticator

I need to get value of CheckBoxPreference and SwitchPreference.

In account_preferences.xml i have:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User Preferences" />
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="test1" android:title="Test 1" />
    <SwitchPreference android:key="test2" android:title="Test 2" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't access preferences set in account-authenticator in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885445/cant-access-preferences-set-in-account-authenticator-in-android)